# Apply CSS to AngularJS Directive Element Tag

Tags: html, css, angularjs, directive

Can I apply a CSS style to an AngularJS directive that has been defined as an element tag?

I have the following simple directive:

```
app.directive('popupHelp', function ($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      elem.bind('click', function (e) {
        $window.open('http://www.google.com', 'popupHelpWindow', 'width=500,height=500');
        console.log("I'm going to get you help on: " + attrs.popupHelp);
      });

      // cleanup
      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        elem.unbind('click');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Which I call with the following:

```
<a popup-help="csshelp">GET ME HELP!</a>
```

Browsers do not give anchor tags a `cursor: pointer` style unless they have an `href` associated with them. I would like to fix this in my CSS and also have `cursor: pointer` applied when the `popup-help` directive is associated with the anchor.

I could just redefine the whole anchor:

```
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

... but I would prefer to tighten up the definition to only apply to what I'm really changing.

I could also redefine the directive to be a full element, but I would also like to avoid that for code styling reasons.

Can I create a CSS definition that captures a directive attribute?

Comment: For accessibility I'd add an empty `href` attribute. AngularJS tolerates that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to define a class in the HTML markup you could also use

```
elem.addClass('foo')
```

To define a class in the directive itself.

---

If you really don't want to resort to classes you could do:

```
elem.css('cursor','pointer');
```

or

```
elem.attr('style','cursor: pointer');
```

Comment: Went the `addClass` route, to make the HTML cleaner. I'd be curious to hear why someone thought this solution is not appropriate (i.e., the down vote).

Comment: I recommend only using jQuery as a last resort. It's not really needed in this case. (the downvote was mine)

Comment: @HankScorpio This isn't jQuery. It's the built in jqLite. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: That's not really the point. jqLite is just a "lite" version of jQuery. It's essentially the same.
As well as not being needed, this also blurs the line between presentation (view) and your code. They should be distinctly separate where possible. Sometimes things just can't be done without using jQuery/jqLite, this isn't one of them.

Comment: I agree with you, but that wasn't what the OP wanted. Moreover, you shouldn't downvote answers based on your personal philosophy. Both of our answers are equally valid.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class to your element and style it that way. It doesn't really matter whether or not your directive is used as an attribute or element.

```
<a class="foo" popup-help="csshelp">GET ME HELP!</a>
```

---

```
.foo {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```